# Faster input scanning

Tags: string, go

I am attempting to solve the SPOJ question that can be found [here](http://www.spoj.com/problems/INTEST/)

Following is my solution:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "bufio"
import "os"

func main() {
    var n, k int
    var num int
    var divisible int

    in := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

    fmt.Fscan(in, &n)
    fmt.Fscan(in, &k)

    for n > 0 {
        fmt.Fscan(in, &num)

        if num%k == 0 {
            divisible++
        }

        n--
    }

    fmt.Println(divisible)
}
```

The code works fine. The issue here is that I get a timeout when I execute it in SPOJ.

I was first using only `fmt.Scan` but I then came across [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/W08rFBcHKbc) thread that suggested that I use `bufio` instead for faster input scanning.

But I still get a timeout issue. I am only looping to get all the inputs and within this loop itself I determine whether the input is divisible or not. So, I believe that its not the loop but the input scanning that's taking time. How can I improve this to read the input faster? Or is the issue somewhere else?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [`bufio.Scanner`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner) to read lines from the input.

And since we're always reading numbers, we can create a highly optimized converter to get the number. We should avoid using [`Scanner.Text()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner.Text) which creates a `string` as we can obtain the number just from the raw bytes returned by [`Scanner.Bytes()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner.Bytes). `Scanner.Text()` returns the same token as `Scanner.Bytes()` but it first converts to `string` which is obviously slower and generates "garbage" and work for the gc.

So here is a converter function which obtains an `int` from the raw bytes:

```
func toInt(buf []byte) (n int) {
    for _, v := range buf {
        n = n*10 + int(v-'0')
    }
    return
}
```

This `toInt()` works because the `[]byte` contains the UTF-8 encoded byte sequence of the string representation of the decimal format of the number, which contains only digits in the range of `'0'..'9'` whose UTF-8 encoded bytes are mapped one-to-one (one byte is used for one digit). The mapping from digit to byte is simply a shift: `'0' -> 48`, `'1' -> 49` etc.

Using this your complete application:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    var n, k, c int
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)

    scanner.Scan()
    fmt.Sscanf(scanner.Text(), "%d %d", &n, &k)

    for ;n > 0; n-- {
        scanner.Scan()
        if toInt(scanner.Bytes())%k == 0 {
            c++
        }
    }

    fmt.Println(c)
}

func toInt(buf []byte) (n int) {
    for _, v := range buf {
        n = n*10 + int(v-'0')
    }
    return
}
```

This solution is about 4 times faster than calling [`strconv.Atoi()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Atoi) for example.

**Notes:**

In the above solution I assumed input is valid, that is it always contains valid numbers and contains at least `n` lines after the first (which gives us `n` and `k`).

If the input is closed after `n+1` lines, we can use a simplified `for` (and we don't even need to decrement and rely on `n`):

```
for scanner.Scan() {
    if toInt(scanner.Bytes())%k == 0 {
        c++
    }
}
```

Comment: How to stop scanning input? `scanner.Scan()` loop continues even if I only press enter key

Comment: @callmekatootie `scanner.Scan()` returns `true` until there is input. If you want to test it locally, use a modified loop which counts the lines. See edited answer.

Comment: Ok. The variable `n` which is the number of inputs. So, I assume that if I need to stop after n inputs, I replace the for condition with the `n>0`  condition and move the `scanner.Scan()` inside the for loop

Comment: @callmekatootie I edited the answer to avoid confusion. The full example now loops to read `n` lines. The simplified loop is now moved to the "Notes" section.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do you "close" input when testing locally? I mean, I tried hitting the enter key without input, it still took it and did not stop. Ctrl+C terminates the program itself. So how to "close" input but not stop program?

Comment: @callmekatootie, Ctrl+D if you are using Linux

Comment: @kostya Yup. That does it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `bufio.Scanner` (as suggested in the thread you mentioned):

```
fmt.Scan(&n)
fmt.Scan(&k)

scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
for n > 0 {
    scanner.Scan()
    k, _ := strconv.Atoi(scanner.Text())
    ...
```

Comment: This works as well. However, the time taken is 1.08 seconds. The other solution was accepted because it took 0.28 seconds.

Comment: @callmekatootie, yes makes sense. `scanner.Text()` allocates memory and that what it makes it slower than the solution by @icza

Answer (score 1):

I coded 3 versions to compare them.
The first using `fmt.Scanf("%d", &v)`, the second converting numbers from bytes (like @icza), and the third converting using `strconv.Atoi`. To use the functions I initializated scanner in that way:

```
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
scanner.Split(bufio.ScanWords)
```

So, every time I call scanner.Scan, it returns a token splitted by spaces.
And the functions follow:

```
func scanFromBytes(scanner *bufio.Scanner) (n int) {
    scanner.Scan()

    buf := scanner.Bytes()
    for _, v := range buf {
        n = n*10 + int(v-'0')
    }

    return
}
```

And:

```
func scanAtoi(scanner *bufio.Scanner) (n int) {
    scanner.Scan()
    
    n, _ = strconv.Atoi(scanner.Text())

    return
}
```

I have tested with a big file (40k tests), reading about 8 integers per test.
The `fmt.Scanf` solution, takes about 1.9s, as expected (more than the others).
In the two functions I got about 0.8s. But the `scanAtoi` always takes about 0.05s less than `scanFromBytes`, except for the very first time (maybe some caching occurs).