# implementing bubble sort with go

Tags: go, bubble-sort, purely-functional

Please help me implement bubble sort.It works fine if I call it with a hardcoded slice from the main() but if I call it with dynamic input from Scan it breaks

here is my code so far:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Enter a maximum of 10 numbers: ")

    var inputs int
    fmt.Scanln(&inputs)
    inputSlice := make([]int, inputs)

    BubbleSort(inputSlice)

    fmt.Println(inputSlice)

}

func BubbleSort(input []int) {

    for i := 0; i < len(input)-1; i++ {
        for j := 0; j < len(input)-i-1; j++ {
            Swap(input, j)
        }
    }
}

func Swap(input []int, j int) {
    if input[j] > input[j+1] {
        input[j], input[j+1] = input[j+1], input[j]
    }
}
```

terminal:

```
coder:~/project$ go run bubblesort.go
Enter a maximum of 10 numbers:
12 24 54 65 11
coder:~/project$ 4 54 65 11
bash: 4: command not found
```

Comment: Why do you delete the previous question and literally copy-paste the same question again?

Comment: How does it break? What is the error message? The second error in your terminal occurred because you didn't run the program first.

Comment: @shouravRahman: You are reading an integer, not a sequence of integers (`var inputs int`). That's why it stops reading after it detected an integer and the rest is just interpreted as shell input once the command has exited.

Comment: i ran it one time and then it prompts for a input.after giving inputs i hit enter again and then breaks.what am i missing here@SteffenUllrich

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read a set of integers separated by space in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39565055/read-a-set-of-integers-separated-by-space-in-golang)

Comment: i ran it one time and then it prompts for a input.after giving inputs i hit enter again and then breaks.what am i missing here@SteffenUllrich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a little debugging by adding print lines in between your codes and see what's actually happening, you were just reading input the wrong way from command line

After Taking Reference from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39565055/read-a-set-of-integers-separated-by-space-in-golang) as posted above in comments by [Steffen Ullrich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3081018/steffen-ullrich)

[View In Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/9wLT5Q7DLTM)

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println(`Enter the number of integers`)
    var n int
    if m, err := Scan(&n); m != 1 {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(`Enter the integers`)
    inputSlice := make([]int, n)
    ReadN(inputSlice, 0, n)

    //Your Input Printing Out
    fmt.Println(inputSlice)

    //Calling Function
    BubbleSort(inputSlice)

    //Output
    fmt.Println(inputSlice)

}

func BubbleSort(input []int) {

    for i := 0; i < len(input)-1; i++ {
        for j := 0; j < len(input)-i-1; j++ {
            Swap(input, j)
        }
    }
}

func Swap(input []int, j int) {
    if input[j] > input[j+1] {
        input[j], input[j+1] = input[j+1], input[j]
    }
}

//Additional Functions
func ReadN(all []int, i, n int) {
    if n == 0 {
        return
    }
    if m, err := Scan(&all[i]); m != 1 {
        panic(err)
    }
    ReadN(all, i+1, n-1)
}

func Scan(a *int) (int, error) {
    return fmt.Scan(a)
}
```